# AspNetCore WEB/REST API object as parameter? vs passing Json?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I want to know the pros and cons of passing method parameter as object vs passing Json in context of AspNetCore WEB/REST API.
For my application, ASPNET REST API is done in C#, clients are python.
I suspect for interoperability, Json is better.

Example,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/SubmitBatchRequestJsonWay")]
public void SubmitBatchRequest(string jsonBatchRequest)
{
    return;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/SubmitBatchRequestPassPoco")]
public void SubmitBatchRequest2(SomeRequest req)
{
    return;
}
```

But i'm not sure if i am missing anything here?

Thanks

[Passing Object as an parameter in Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702235/passing-object-as-an-parameter-in-web-api)
[How to pass object as parameter in Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538171/how-to-pass-object-as-parameter-in-web-api)

Comment: What are you asking? Can you give examples?

Comment: Wait...you do understand that ASP.NET Core will deserialize JSON to an object, right? Perhaps you should read ["Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on Microsoft's docs site?

Comment: question is - what's pros and cons passing poco entity as paramters to REST API, vs JSON strings (better interop)

Comment: Example added in original post

Comment: How are JSON strings "better interop"? I really don't understand that part. Doesn't the client send JSON in either case? Aren't you just taking control from the framework deserializing your JSON and moving the deserialization to your controller method? I'm not sure why you want to make more work for yourself.

Comment: "How JSON better interop" --> SomeRequest is a POCO class in C# dll. How can Python serialize/deserialize it? Can use Avro which actually serialize/deserialize to/from Json?

Comment: See my previous comment: "Wait...you do understand that ASP.NET Core will deserialize JSON to an object, right?" - ASP.NET Core _does not_ accept some binary form of your C# class. It will deserialize JSON into a C# class. _You do not have to do this manually_.

Comment: ASPNET deserialize JSON into POCO-- thanks didnt know

Comment: Likewise it will do the same with responses (POCO->JSON).